# use global scss files in reactjs compoent scss file

Tags: css, algorithm, reactjs, sass, package.json

I am trying to develop a web application using sass and reactjs.

The Sass structure is like the one in the image attached.

Image - ![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4nGL.png

The library.scss and settings.scss file is imported in the styles.scss file.

Inside each reactjs component, I have a js, scss, css.

- MainLayout (Component)

  - MainLayout.js
  - MainLayout.css
  - MainLayout.scss

Now, all the breakpoints, grids, etc generated in the "style.css" file and I want to use it in the "MainLayout.scss".

So, in the  "MainLayout.scss" file, I did

@import '../../assets/css/styles.scss';

.main-content {

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;

@include from-breakpoint(tablet-portrait) {
    position: relative;
}
```

}

But, I get this error stated below :

=> changed: C:\projects\vliegtickets-frontend\src\components\MainLayout\MainLayout.scss

{
  "status": 1,

"file": "C:/projects/vliegtickets-frontend/src/components/MainLayout/MainLayout.scss",

"line": 53,

"column": 14,

"message": "no mixin named grid-desktop\n\nBacktrace:\n\tsrc/components/MainLa
yout/MainLayout.scss:53, in mixin `@content`\n\tsrc/assets/css/library/_breakpoi
nts.scss:16, in mixin `from-breakpoint`\n\tsrc/components/MainLayout/MainLayout.
scss:52",

"formatted": "Error: no mixin named grid-desktop\n\n

Backtrace:\n
\tsrc/components/MainLayout/MainLayout.scss:53, in mixin `@content`\n       \tsr
c/assets/css/library/_breakpoints.scss:16, in mixin `from-breakpoint`\n       \t
src/components/MainLayout/MainLayout.scss:52\n        on line 53 of src/componen
ts/MainLayout/MainLayout.scss\n>> \t\t\t\t@include grid-desktop;\n   -----------
--^\n"
}

Can someone please help me with this ? What should I do to to make my "scss" files inside the components make use of the "style.scss"?

Comment: first of all, you have to transpile `scss` into `css` files, do you do that?

Comment: Yes, i did that, I have the "style.css" file too.

Comment: did you check if you correctly wrote `grid-desktop`, it says he cant find it. 

I would suggest to import all scss files into one scss file, then import that global `scss` file into `App.jsx` for example.

Comment: Yes, I have imported the grid, breakpoint inside the style.scss file. If I create a new "scss" file inside the "assets" folder and use the "grid-desktop", then it works perfectly fine.                                                                                                   But if I use it inside the react component folder, where i have the "scss" and "js" files, then It says it cannot load the @mixin.

Comment: why would you use it inside the react component folder?